git clone on azure virtual machine fails

I have created a virtual machine on azure

Additionally, I have taken the ssh public key from azure and added to github ssh keys

Now I ssh from my machine to azure virtual machine

On the virtual machine $ git clone git@github.com:my_account/my_software.git. I get the following error
Cloning into 'my_software'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


what am I missing?
--edit---
adding some screenshots
github

azure


Is that all the error says, or is there more you aren't telling us?

thats all in the error message ...i have just changed the name of the my repository..above

What do you get from ssh -T git@github.com from the Azure VM?

$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

What about ssh -Tv git@github.com? (I suspect this is a networking issue - that Azure isn't allowing you to connect to github.com port 22 - but this verbose output will be more conclusive.)

can paste only limited here.. from look of it port 22 is fine but i don't have private key stored in .ssh folder. azure does not give you private key...
....debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established....debug1: Trying private key: /home/saquants-azure/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)...

On the virtual machine, I had to add the key using ssh-add.
So the sequence of steps on my azure VM were:
Install git
$ sudo apt install git

generate key (email here can be any unique email)
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@gmail.com" 

Note: on prompt save to file ~/.ssh/id_github
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_github.pub

On github.com --> Settings --> SSH and GPG keys -->  New SSH keys --> copy paste output of cat id_github.pub
Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent <-- The step I was missing
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_github

test the connection
$ ssh -vT git@github.com


(1) All of this is in the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh (2) This isn't programming.

@matt Would it belong on Super User SE? Yes, I guess.

@matt, thanks for the links... did not realize that only programming questions can be asked ..in hindsight it is easy but it took me a while to figure out
